TikZ, polyglossia, \footnote interference?
With this MWE I can either setotherlanguage{latin} or get the tikz picture to print as desired in a footnote, but I haven't figured out how to do both. Doing both causes "missing \endcsname" errors followed by "\xparse function is not expandable," and the pics for the angles of the bottom line of the triangle are not understood and get mangled. The full document is a book that uses many languages, and it is odd that only the call for latin causes trouble. Here's the MWE. I hope I've posted it correctly now. Pardon the newbie mistake:
```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,babel}
\usepackage[no-math,quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\tikzset{my angle1/.style = {draw,
    angle radius=7mm, 
    angle eccentricity=1.1, 
    right, inner sep=1pt}}
\tikzset{my angle/.style = {draw,
    angle radius=7mm, 
    angle eccentricity=1.1, 
    left, inner sep=1pt}}
\begin{document}
also\footnote{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate[label=below:$A$] (a) --
(4,0) coordinate[label=below:$D$] (d) --
3.115,3.375) coordinate[label=above:$tree$] (b) -- cycle;
\pic[my angle1, "$\SI{48}{\degree}$"] {angle = d--a--b};
\pic[my angle, "$\SI{74}{\degree}$"] {angle = b--d--a};
\end{tikzpicture}}
und so weiter
\end{document}
```

When I set both latin and make the footnote command, this is what happens to the figure:

When I comment out the setotherlanguage{latin}, I get:

which is what I want, but I forfeit the latin.
I put the usepackage{tikz} before setting the languages due to the answer regarding interference between polyglossia and navigator. I have also religiously deleted the aux files with each unsuccessful xelatex run. I'm using TeXLive 2024 on ubuntu.

Please never post images of code. An image of code is useless. It cannot be copy-pasted to reproduce the problem, it cannot be indexed and it cannot be accessed at all by screen-reading software.  Since you've provided no means to test, my best guess is the babel tikzlibrary is the culprit. Remove it. But I'm certainly not retying your code to see if I'm right.

The latin gloss makes " active, which tikz does not like, you can disable it temporarily
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,babel}
\usepackage[no-math,quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\tikzset{my angle1/.style = {draw,
    angle radius=7mm, 
    angle eccentricity=1.1, 
    right, inner sep=1pt}}
\tikzset{my angle/.style = {draw,
    angle radius=7mm, 
    angle eccentricity=1.1, 
    left, inner sep=1pt}}
\begin{document}
also\shorthandoff{"}\footnote{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate[label=below:$A$] (a) --
(4,0) coordinate[label=below:$D$] (d) --
(3.115,3.375) coordinate[label=above:$tree$] (b) -- cycle;
\pic[my angle1, "$\SI{48}{\degree}$"] {angle = d--a--b};
\pic[my angle, "$\SI{74}{\degree}$"] {angle = b--d--a};
\end{tikzpicture}}\shorthandon{"}
und so weiter
\end{document}

